# 75 people; 13 stops; find the different sets of tickets they may be holding.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

> A train going from London to Cambridge stops at 12 intermediate stops. 75 people enter the train from London with 75 different tickets of the same class. No. of different sets of tickets they may be holding is:___

I am not able to understand the solution given:
Total number of different tickets is $13+12+11+10+\cdots+1=91$
Hence required number=$\binom{91}{75}$

What is this total number of different tickets?

Comment: From this description, I have no idea honestly

Comment: @Fimpellizieri but is this the right answer?

Comment: I honestly can't tell what the quesiton is asking. It seems to be missing information or otherwise just poorly written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can gather, the $13 + 12 + \dots + 1$ portion is counting how many different tickets are possible. There are $13$ possible tickets that are for trips 1 stop apart (London to station 1, station 1 to station 2, etc.), $12$ tickets for trips that are two stops apart (since we can't get on at the second last stop and travel for two stops) $\dots$ and only $1$ trip that is $13$ stops long. Hence the total number of different tickets is $91$ and we are picking $75$ distinct tickets, one for each passenger. Therefore, the answer is ${91}\choose{75}$.